# Recursive input calling in Snakemake rule

Tags: snakemake

I am writing rule to process some data:
data in directory will be something like:

`myfirst.trim_1P, myfirst.trim_2P, mysecond.trim_1P, mysecond.trim_2P,...`

```
rule trim_data:
        input:"{dataset}/{sample}.trim_{r}P"
        output:"{dataset}/{sample}.{r}.fastq"
        params:
            length=14
        shell:
            """
            reformat.sh forcetrimleft="{params.length}" in="{input}" out="{output}"
            """
```

I have this error:

```
WorkflowError:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
If building the DAG exceeds the recursion limit
```

`myDir/myfirst.1.trimed.1.trimed.2.trimed.2.trimed.2....`

Why it run in recursive way if the output different from the input? and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild guess... Maybe the wildcards capture more then they should since they are interpreted as regular expression. If `{dataset}`, `{sample}` and `{r}` take a defined list of values, try constraining their scope with:

```
wildcard_constraints:
    dataset= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in DATASET]),
    sample= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in SAMPLE]),
    r= '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in R]),
```

Where DATASET, SAMPLE and R are lists of values (e.g. `R= ['1', '2']`)

Comment: Thanks, this could be the case I will test it and give feedback.

Comment: unfortunately, it did not work. I will try to figure something else, Thanks.

Comment: So the error was in another downstream rule that could cause this recursion I fixed it and add some constraints on the name like this `rule bam2fastq:
    input:
        datain="{dataset}/{sample}.{filter, ^[0-9]}.bam"
    output:
        dataout="{dataset}/{sample}.{filter}.reads.fastq"
    run:
        shell("""
            bedtools bamtofastq -i "{input.datain}" -fq "{output.dataout}"
             """)`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error (below). This turned out to be caused by the fact the file name for the rule output was identical to a different rule. Changing the name of the output file fixed this error.

Code:

```
rule merge_sample_chr:
    input:

            bcftools=config["bcftools"],
            chr_list=expand(config["vcf_dir_ase"]+"/Eagle/all_{{sample}}_chr{this_chr}_sorted.vcf.gz",this_chr=CHRS)
    params:
            chr_list=expand("I="+config["vcf_dir_ase"]+"/Eagle/all_{{sample}}_chr{this_chr}_sorted.vcf.gz",this_chr=CHRS)

    output:
            vcf=config["vcf_dir_ase"]+"/Eagle/all_{sample}.vcf.gz"
    shell:
            """
            {input.bcftools} concat {input.chr_list} -Oz -o {output}
            """
```

Error:

```
WorkflowError:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in __instancecheck__
If building the DAG exceeds the recursion limit, this is likely due to a cyclic dependency.E.g. you might have a sequence of rules that can generate their own input. Try to make the output files more specific. A common pattern is 
Problematic file pattern: /path/samplid_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_chr1_.vcf.gz
```

Comment: That is right I mentioned that in @dariober answer, you can fix it by either changing the names of output as you mentioned or put some constraints as I did.